# Terme français pour "corporate welfare"?

Tags: traduction

En anglais, le terme "[corporate welfare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_welfare)" est un terme péjoratif pour décrire la subvention d'entreprises par le gouvernement, alors qu'il n'y a pas d'externalités positives.

Est-ce qu'il y a un équivalent français qui conserve la même connotation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La connotation péjorative de « *corporate welfare* » est principalement américaine, le mot « *welfare* » étant plutôt positif lorsqu'on s'éloigne des États-Unis. En français de France, je ne vois pas d'équivalent direct.

La base [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=%22corporate+welfare%22) recense un certain nombre d'occurrences, principalement canadiennes comme souvent, et ici en particulier beaucoup sont issues de débats parlementaires. (Attention, il y a quelques traductions automatiques dans le lot.) Un terme qui revient souvent est « sociétés parasites » ou de « parasitisme des entreprises », dans lequel le côté parasite est clairement exprimé. On trouve aussi le terme syntaxiquement neutre d'« aide sociale aux entreprises ».

(Note : ne pas confondre ce sens de « *corporate welfare* » du sens plus ancien de prospérité collective par rapport à la prospérité ou au bien-être individuel (« *individual welfare* »).)

Comment: « Aide sociale aux sociétés parasites » est attesté par Termium Plus, la banque de données terminologiques et linguistiques du gouvernement du Canada : http://www.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=&index=ent&srchtxt=CORPORATE%20WELFARE